# SharePoint Multi-Line Text (Plain Text) field, how do I get a Carriage Return

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a Sharepoint list app and I am using a multiline text (plain text) field for a history log.  I use a workflow that appends the latest entry to the top of the history entries so I gte a running track record.  This is done using stringbuilder...

The wuestion is how the heck do I get a blank line or carriage return to separate the entries?  I have tried enevrything 
, physically putting a blank line in. etc...

Answer (score 0):

In String Build, directly set the value like this:
[image]

It will separate the entries with the lines:

[image]